# Setting Rails files encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with enconding (i think) in Rails. When i put for example:

```
flash[:notice] = "ąęćół"
```

in rails controller i see 500 error page. I set default encoding for MYSQL on

```
UTF-8
```

but where i can set it for rails files?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the file where you want to write text in Unicode

Comment: is there some other way? I have many files when i need to do it. Hmm good solution will be a I18n file for translations then...

Comment: Yes you should put the texts in the yml files in config/locales. Please accept the answer anyway as this might come handy if you need to do specific testing for Unicode in your specs ;)

Comment: All you need is [a comment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Encoding.html#label-Script+encoding) containing `coding: utf-8` in the first line of the file (or, after the shebang). The `-*-` are unnecessary